# Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. EOFError (EOFError)[Fluentd using helm on kubernetes]

Tags: kubernetes, elasticsearch, kibana, helm, fluentd

I'm installing elasticsearch, kibana and fluentd in kubernetes with helm chart Elasticsearch and kibana pods stand up smoothly, but fluentd pods don't stand up I get the following errors:

```
2023-06-13 13:29:39 +0000 [warn]: #0 [filter_kube_metadata] !! The environment variable 'K8S_NODE_NAME' is not set to the node name which can affect the API server and watch efficiency !!
2023-06-13 13:29:39 +0000 [info]: adding match in @KUBERNETES pattern="**" type="relabel"
2023-06-13 13:29:39 +0000 [info]: adding filter in @DISPATCH pattern="**" type="prometheus"
2023-06-13 13:29:39 +0000 [info]: adding match in @DISPATCH pattern="**" type="relabel"
2023-06-13 13:29:39 +0000 [info]: adding match in @OUTPUT pattern="**" type="elasticsearch"
2023-06-13 13:29:41 +0000 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. EOFError (EOFError)
2023-06-13 13:29:41 +0000 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 14. Retry to communicate after 2 second(s).
2023-06-13 13:29:45 +0000 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. EOFError (EOFError)
2023-06-13 13:29:45 +0000 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 13. Retry to communicate after 4 second(s).
2023-06-13 13:29:53 +0000 [warn]: #0 Could not communicate to Elasticsearch, resetting connection and trying again. EOFError (EOFError)
2023-06-13 13:29:53 +0000 [warn]: #0 Remaining retry: 12. Retry to communicate after 8 second(s).
```

**command for elasticsearch:**

`helm install elasticsearch-master elastic/elasticsearch -n efk`

**command for fluentd:**

`helm install fluentd fluent/fluentd --set elasticsearch.password=22qz66p1gsr8ELA1 -n efk`

**command for kibana:**

`helm install kibana elastic/kibana -n efk`

**elasticsearch image:**

```
Image:       docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.5.1
Ports:       9200/TCP, 9300/TCP
Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
```

**kibana image:**

```
  Image:      docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.5.1
    Port:       5601/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
```

**fluentd image:**

```
Image:      fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.15.2-debian-elasticsearch7-1.0
Port:       24231/TCP
Host Port:  0/TCP
```

fluentd config map elasticsearch output

```
04_outputs.conf: |-
    <label @OUTPUT>
      <match **>
        @type elasticsearch
        host elasticsearch-master
        port 9200
        path ""
        user elastic
        password 22qz66p1gsr8ELA1
      </match>
    </label>
```

How can I fix